# Removing only one drawn image from screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, image

I have drawn 2 images on my Form with this code:

```
Public Class drawimage

Dim image = Image.FromFile("E:\1.png")
Dim image2 = Image.FromFile("E:\2.png")
Private Sub testbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testbutton.Click
Me.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100)
Me.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(image2, 200, 200, 100,100)
end sub
```

And I want to remove one of the images programmatically, so I tried with this code:

```
Me.CreateGraphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)
```

But that cleared all my images. Can I clear only one image? The one named "image".

Comment: that is not valid code.  where is the code located in an event? a sub? where is it called from?

Comment: already fixed, please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing and painting things which you want to persist, needs to be done in the Paint event.  This is so that every time Windows tells your form to repaint, your images will get drawn.  As it is, if another form floats across it, they will be lost.  Also, it keeps you from having to create Graphics objects.

To get rid if one, you need a flag.  Something like this will work:

```
Private drawBoth As Boolean = True
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    drawBoth = Not drawBoth
    Me.Invalidate
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100)
    If drawBoth Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img2, 200, 200, 100, 100)
    End If

End Sub
```

`Image` is a bad name for a bitmap or picture because there is an Image Type in .NET which you are even using.  Things (including you) can get confused between **your** image and `System.Drawing.Image`

Comment: it toggles the state of whether you want to draw both or not.  rather than a variable and a button, you could also just evaluate a check box control `If chkDrawBoth.Checked Then....`  otherwise you have to restart the app to make them both get drawn again.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw an Rectangle over it.

```
Me.CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Me.BackColor), 0, 0, 100,100)
```

Comment: You should do all you drawing on a form in the forms OnPaint event so it will be there if the form has to redraw itself.  An example will be restoring the form after it was minimized